# How to get Notification message in android notification bar in titanium ? How to play sound in android device visible as well in App background mode

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy

I Have configured sound as background service as well as setup for local-notification in IOS device. I want to make it same in android using titanium studio. 
I have noticed that many of docs provided for android notification is not available. Have anyone some idea or source code to built local notification in android?As well as how to play sound in android using titanium ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation:

- https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Notification

or if you want to support bigText/bigStyle you can have a look at this module:

- Module: https://github.com/falkolab/Ti.NotificationFactory
- Documentation: https://github.com/falkolab/Ti.NotificationFactory/blob/master/android/documentation/index.md